# How can i earn by putting admob ads on my android application

Tags: android, admob

How does admob pays the developers. Does it pay for just displaying the ad or clicking the ad?
How does it pay, i dont have any paypal account. I am from Nepal.Does it pay if i have account in some banks over here ?

Answer (score 0):

AdMob pays for clicking the ads, displaying is not enough.

According to this link [19 September 2013: AdMob launched to more countries](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3406291?hl=en-GB) AdMob is now available in Nepal.

The new AdMob (rollout out last month) can pay to a bank account but you should check how it works for Nepal.

Comment: Thank you. Nepal is also listed there.Can u tell me what is the payment method?

Comment: You will need to try it for your location:
https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3006274?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2772055